# Help identifying this reed?

Tags: identification

I  wan't to plant some reed in my garden, and came across some that I think looked nice.

Anyone who can help identify these?

[image: Reed]

The picture is from Oslo, Norway, and it's planted by the municipality.

Comment: Reeds are wetland plants. Are these growing in water? Are you looking for plants to grow in water?

Comment: I don't intend to grow it in water, and these are not growing in water/wetland. They grow a couple of meters above and away from a river. The soil is not particularly wet there.

Comment: Reeds are hollow, Sedges have triangular stems ("sedges have edges" is a useful ID phrase in English), and Grasses are round-stemmed. If possible, cut a flowering stem and see which of these applies. This would help in the ID, although it may not be possible to give you an ID until the plant blooms again this summer. I believe it's a grass, myself. If possible, please update this question with a photo taken in spring and again in summer (showing the flower heads). If you get an ID from a municipal worker, please enter your own answer.

Comment: @Jurp thank you, very informative. I'll do some more research when spring arrives, and update this post. :)

Comment: Contacted the municipality, and the person suggested Calamagrostis x acutiflora ‘Karl Foerster’. But she wasn't sure, and connected me with ones responsible for this area, so hopefully this will get resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *Calamagrostis × acutiflora* 'Karl Foerster'? Even if it isn't, this is an excellent grass. Cut back hard each winter. More details [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/72074/calamagrostis-x-acutiflora-karl-foerster/details).

Comment: I doubt that it's a Calamagrostis because the seedheads aren't particularly showy and it seems to be taller than 1.2m (although perhaps it's in a raised bed), but on the other hand, it IS coming out of winter.

Comment: This one looks very nice and similar, but as @Jurp mentions, it's a bit taller than what this one usually is, it looks like. The reeds where higher than my girlfriend (1.6-1.7m high). But either way this looks very nice, and absolutely something I will concider if I don't find anything even closer. :)